# Kotlin @JvmStatic and accidental override in a companion object

Tags: swing, kotlin

I'm working on a Swing look&feel using kotlin. In order to create a UI, Swing requires to have a static method `createUI` with the following signature:

```
class ButtonUI: BasicButtonUI() {
    ...
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic fun createUI(p0: JComponent): ComponentUI {
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

and then it is called via reflection in Swing code:

```
m = uiClass.getMethod("createUI", new Class[]{JComponent.class});
```

Unfortunately, the code above cannot be compiled by the kotlin compiler because of:

```
Error:(88, 9) Kotlin: Accidental override: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (createUI(Ljavax/swing/JComponent;)Ljavax/swing/plaf/ComponentUI;):
    fun createUI(c: JComponent): ComponentUI
    fun createUI(p0: JComponent!): ComponentUI!
```

Is there a workaround for this case?

Comment: Did you try `@JvmStatic override fun createUI`?

Comment: @shiftpsh it's not applicable within the object declaration.

Answer (score 5):

it's a kotlin [bug KT-12993](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12993). Unfortunately, the bug is not fixed yet. just using [java](/questions/tagged/java) implements your `ButtonUI` or switch between [java](/questions/tagged/java) and kotlin to solving the problem if you want to let kotlin implements your ui logic. for example, you should define a **peer** between [java](/questions/tagged/java) and kotlin.

the java code as below:

```
public class ButtonUI extends BasicButtonUI {
    private ButtonUIPeer peer;

    public ButtonUI(ButtonUIPeer peer) {
        this.peer = peer;
    }

    @Override
    public void installUI(JComponent c) {
        peer.installUI(c, () -> super.installUI(c));
    }

    // override other methods ...


    public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent c) {
        // create the peer which write by kotlin 
        //                        |
        return new ButtonUI(new YourButtonUIPeer());
    }
}


interface ButtonUIPeer {
    void installUI(Component c, Runnable parentCall);
    //adding other methods for the ButtonUI
}
```

the kotlin code as below:

```
class YourButtonUIPeer : ButtonUIPeer {
    override fun installUI(c: Component, parentCall: Runnable) {
      // todo: implements your own ui logic
    }
}
```

**IF** you have more than half dozen methods to implements, you can using the [Proxy Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) just delegate request to the target `ButtonUI` which implemented in kotlin (many IDE support generates delegate methods for a field). for example:

```
public class ButtonUIProxy extends BasicButtonUI {
    private final BasicButtonUI target;
    //1. move the cursor to here ---^
    //2. press `ALT+INSERT`
    //3. choose `Delegate Methods` 
    //4. select all public methods and then click `OK`

    public ButtonUIProxy(BasicButtonUI target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent c){
        // class created by kotlin     ---v
        return new ButtonUIProxy(new ButtonUI());
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. I'm not sure that the bug you're referring to describes the same problem. I'm using fallback to java as a workaround right now, but I'm looking for a more solid approach.

Comment: @dimafeng this is the actually [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-12993).

Answer (score 3):

In latest version of Kotlin 1.3.70 the error can be suppressed with `@Suppress("ACCIDENTAL_OVERRIDE")`. I am not sure since which version it works.